# Check data-counter value exists or not and adding class

Tags: jquery

I've rows like

```
<table id='tbl'>
<tr data-counter="1" class="active">/tr>
<tr data-counter="2">/tr>
<tr data-counter="3">/tr>
<tr data-counter="4">/tr>
<tr data-counter="5" class="active">/tr>
```

I just want to check whether the row exists or not with the data-counter. I want to add the class from 2nd to 4th row and remove the class for existing rows.

```
for(var i = 2;i <=4  i++){ 
        $('.active').removeClass('active'); // Remove class to already existing class rows. 
        if($('#tblInbox tbody tr[data-counter="'+i+'"]').length){ // If the records are already available.  
            console.log("i::"+i);

            $('#tblInbox tbody').find('tr[data-counter="' + i + '"]').addClass('active');

        }
```

}

Is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: With jQuery you can use the .data() function. 
    $('#selector').data('counter')
Adil's and Hiral's answers are much better solutions though

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 2; i <= 4; i++) {
    if ($('#tbl').find('tr[data-counter="' + i + '"]').length) {
        // do something
        $('#tbl').find('tr[data-counter="' + i + '"]').addClass('active');
    }
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/r27SG)

Comment: Thanks hiral.. But, its adding the class only to 4th tr.. But not from  2nd to 4th....if($('#tblInbox tbody tr[data-counter="'+i+'"]').length){ // If the records are already available. 
    console.log("i::"+i);
    $('.active').removeClass('active'); // Remove class to already existing class rows. 
    $('#tblInbox tbody').find('tr[data-counter="' + i + '"]').addClass('active');
         
      }

Comment: I've just edited my question again. Please check it.

Comment: @user3118692 [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/r27SG/). it is adding active class to 2,3,4 `tr`

Comment: Hiral.. I edited the question. I want to remove the class for the existing tr's and add the class for the others.. Thank you :)

Comment: Hiral, if you don't mind can you give me your email ID, so that we can discuss in detail?

Comment: lets continue in chat

Comment: which chat? in gmail?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have td in the rows to put the data.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9HecK/)**

```
$('#tbl td[data-counter]').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':data');       // All elements with data  
$(':not(:data)'); // All elements without data
```

for your question...

```
$('#tbl tr').each(function() {
  if(!$(this).attr('data-timer'))
   {
     // data-attributes does not exits 
   } 
});
```

its better to add class name to rows with data and without data-attribute...